# posting scroll position to return user to same place on page after form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, scroll

<>Im trying to change the value of input so I can return the user to the same place on the page on submission of a form

```
<form> 
 <input type ="text" name="scroll_pos" id ="vert" value="0" > 

</form>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var vp = $(window).scrollTop();

  document.getElementById("vert").value = vp.toString();
});
```

sorry if its aa dumb question but why isnt this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code,

Also i would recommend you to use **ajax**..So you can stay on the same page ***without refreshing*** it when the form get submits.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var position = $("#vert").val();
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#vert").attr('value',scroll);
    //$('input[name=scroll_pos]').val(scroll);
    console.log(scroll);
  });
  
  $(window).scrollTop(position);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="scroll_pos" id="vert" value="0">

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Ajax suggestion. My problem isnt that I cant get the window to scroll on refresh though. The problem is that the value of the input isnt being updated by the scroll event function.

Comment: @DavidGriffiths i have updated my code..please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I found on another site answers an easier way with PHP just by adding an anchor link. I tried it and it worked

In my scenario, after the submission, you return to the same page
so there is the example code

**Here in the form, you put action="£linkoftheanchor¨**

**This is where I want it to return after submit**

Insert one number(¥)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).